# Как через echo выдать переменную

Tags: php

Как через echo выдать переменную "$text" ?

Answer (score 1):

Для таких вопросов есть официальная документация:
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php

```
echo $text;
echo "Какой-то текст: $text";
echo 'Какой-то текст:'.$text;
echo <<<TEXT
Какой-то текст: $text
TEXT;
```